# explicit formula for the j-invariant of binary quartic form

Tags: polynomials, rt.representation-theory

A binary quartic form

$aX^4+bX^3Y+cX^2Y^2+dXY^3+Y^4$

decomposes as a product of linear factors $Y-t_jX$, $j=1,...,4$. 
I would like to have an explicit formula for symmetrization of the crossratio of $t_j$.

Comment: Do you mean the j-invariant of the elliptic curve
$y^2=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+1$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: If you have access to a computer algebra system, you can do
the following.
Let $\xi$  denote a solution to $f(1,\xi)=0$ where $f$
is your quartic. Then $f(X,Y+\xi X)=b'X^3Y+\cdots+Y^4$.
The elliptic curve is now isomorphic to
$y^2=b'x^3+c'x^2+d'x+1$.
Transform it to the usual Weierstrass form and take the 
$j$-invariant. Note that $b'$ etc. will have $\xi$s in them,
but they should all cancel out via the equation $f(1,\xi)=0$ 
in the final result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $j$ invariant is

$j=\frac{S^3}{S^3-27T^2}$

where

$S=a-\frac{bd}{4}+\frac{c^2}{12}$

and

$T=\frac{ac}{6}+\frac{bcd}{48}-\frac{c^3}{216}-\frac{ad^2}{16}-\frac{b^2}{16}$

for more details see my article ["A computational solution to a question by Beauville on the invariants of the binary quintic"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869306000287), J. Algebra **303** (2006) 771-788. The preprint version is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508421).

Comment: Please beware you are calculating J which is j/1728

Comment: There are different conventions for what the proper normalization of $j$ is. Number theorists have their preferred choice. Folks working on moonshine matters have their own. Classical invariant theorists also. The is no universally canonical choice.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam It's certainly true that there is no universally **used** choice. However, up to translation by an integer, there is a **canonical** choice if one wants a formula that has the correct properties in all characteristics, including characteristic 2 and 3. So that would seem to make the "number theorists'" version canonical, up to (as I said) translation by an integer. OTOH, if you're doing complex analysis, one could take the "$j$-invariant" of $X^3+AX+B$ to be $$\frac{(\pi^e+i\tan(\pi//\sqrt2))\cdot4A^3}{4A^3+27B^2},$$ for example. :)